# How should I approach reporting a discriminating comments to my company?

Tags: communication, job-change, bullying

My co-worker had really made very discriminating comments about me. My other co-workers find it too bad. But the situation was nobody including myself reacted against it.

I want to send a this incidence documented, and ideally get my coworker to stop bulling me.  So what is the proper way to report this?  Is there anything I should consider?

Please note:  **This is Western Europe not the United States**

Comment: Perhaps a better question is "how should you approach reporting this to your company?"  This question does not seem terribly constructive or helpful to anyone.

Comment: is this a [document](http://www.ask.com/question/what-is-a-letter-of-experience) to be provided by the company you are going to leave?

Comment: I think this is a good question even though it may be obvious to many of us that sending a company-wide email, regardless of how offended the originator feels, is a very counterproductive idea.

Comment: @teego1967: I appreciate your support

Comment: If this has been going on for years and you only wish to bring it up now that you are in competition for a senior position it looks very suspicious

Comment: Are the discriminating comments still happening or was this an isolated incident 2 years ago? Some more detail may be useful here.

Comment: @Saar, have you talked to your manager? Set up a private meeting with your immediate boss, discuss this issue, and show him your record if necessary. Then plan for the next step **with his guidance and approval**.

Comment: @BeyondSora: Boss knows it. His comments are I have to improve myself for rugged environment.

Comment: @Saar - That update is fine for comments but that edit is not really appropriate in a question.  Which country, it really matters.  The protections vary by country.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's the US or WE if you didn't document the incident as to time, place, description, witnesses, outcome, nobody has anything to work with. I assume that the company you work for has an HR department, which is in charge of enforcing compliance with workplace policies and compliance with applicable law. I take it that as of this writing, you have failed to document the incident and you have not contacted HR. Don't expect to get anywhere if you didn't. If you needed guidance on how to document the incident so that the incident be actionable, contact HR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the company has an HR department and harassment policies, I'd probably suggest setting up a meeting with someone in HR and explain the situation. The key points to note:

- When were the comments said, what did you do about it and what are you asking for now.
- What reaction did your manager give that you feel isn't appropriate as this doesn't resolve the issue

The key here is that it may be worth bringing in HR as they would be the ones to report this if going to your manager isn't working which is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edit

**Send ONLY to the appropriate parties**

*Never* I mean ***NEVER*** send email blasts even among only the management. Select the appropriate parties. (This is likely your boss, his boss, and HR depending on the specifics) Email blasts are **always** seen as unprofessional in this context and could cost you a good recommendation, be it by letter or verbal.

**Should you do this at all?**

You may have a legitimate grievance here, but what is there to gain in doing so. In my opinion the proper solution is to provide details of this issue on the exit interview (purely on documented fact. No "I feel" or "I think") This lets HR and your boss and maybe your boss's boss know that they lost a valuable asset primarily on this situation, and spare you the risk of sullying your recommendations.

**It's all about you**

Remember you have to worry about yourself. If you ruin your reputation because you sent out an email blast on your way out the door than not only did this guy run you out the door, but he also put your future opportunities in jeopardy.

Comment: *In my opinion the proper solution is to provide details of this issue on the exit interview* - This is a very bad idea.   You should avoid airing dirty laundry in an exit interview that you are unwilling to give them a chance to fix.

Comment: Exit interviews are intended on getting the honest opinion of those exiting your company on their own accord. Their entire purpose is to sort out what the company could have done but failed to do to retain an employee.

I wouldn't make a huge thing at the exit interview but not having a reason for quitting is no better than saying the truth. The critical point is not to make it an attack on the coworker rather just make it clear what was happening. That way HR can make an informed decision on if or how they want to react. (also according to saar the boss was aware of the issue)

Comment: I think there is definitely a case for sending these to the appropriate people.  The OP feels bullied, and that is not fair to them.  That said, law and culture vary by country, so you may or may not have success with this approach.

Comment: If they really cared about why you were leaving they would have asked back then.  Dropping a bomb in an exit interview is a good way to get put on their do not rehire list.  Which you think may not matter but most companies will only tell if you are eligible for rehire when asked for a reference.  Being told no you can not be rehired acts as a bad review even if you were an otherwise good employee.

Comment: I'm with Chad, waiting until the exit interview is the worst time to bring it up.  The entire purpose of reporting an issue is to try and effect change.  When you are in an exit interview then it's way too late for the company to do anything at all.  I'd certainly put an employee on a no rehire list if they waited until the exit interview to highlight personality issues that they failed to bring up with the appropriate people.  Mainly because it would show that I couldn't count on them to bring up important issues in a timely manner.

Comment: This question was edited multiple times but in other comments the OP mentioned his boss and others were already aware of the problem but no one did anything about it. In the initial post he had planned to do a company wide email blast issuing this complaint as he quit. That being said it's already a known problem and he's already quitting over it. HR might not be aware but if he calmly explains there was a problem reported to x,y,z and it remained unresolved it should not jeopardize rehire. (Unless there are serious company health issues here)